# How to fix parsing error by moment.js on Safari?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to fix parsing error by moment.js?

```
Const.DATE_MONTH_FORMAT = 'DD-MMM-YYYY';
var fromDate = moment(new Date(period.fromDate)).format(Const.DATE_MONTH_FORMAT);
```

On Firefox, Chrome: `19-Aug-2016`

On Safari: `Invalid date`

On Firefox:
`console.debug(period);`

```
 Object { fromDate="19/Aug/2016",  toDate="30/Aug/2016"}
```

Comment: No, it isn't typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format()` is used for output, not for determining what format the input is in. You're also passing `period.fromDate` to a `Date` constructor, rather than to moment, so you're using the browser's own parsing, which can do whatever it likes when dates don't conform to the JS spec [(which `DD/MMM/YYYY` doesn't)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format). Firefox and Chrome evidently think they can pluck a date from `period.fromDate`, while Safari can't.  You should be able to fix this by passing in the string directly to moment, along with the format of `period.fromDate`, so it can do all the work itself:

```
Const.DATE_MONTH_FORMAT = 'DD-MMM-YYYY';
var fromDate = moment(period.fromDate, "DD/MMM/YYYY").format(Const.DATE_MONTH_FORMAT);
```